# Entity Framework procedure call with navigation properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I want to call a procedure and access the navigation properties afterwards

```
using (DbContext c = new DbContext())
{
    // System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult<Product> 
    List<Product> products = c.myProcedure(id).Include("ProductOptions").ToList();
    // here the .Include() isn't available

}
```

my current approach is loading each navigation property seperately

```
using (DbContext c = new DbContext())
{
    List<Product> products = c.myProcedure(id).ToList();
    foreach(Product p in products)
    {
        if(!o.ProductOptions.IsLoaded)
            p.ProductOptions.Load();
    }
}
```

is working fine but super slow because of the subselect for each item.

Question: Is there a kind of `Include()` function or something else to speed up my code?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

Comment: @Owl there is nothing about this special case

Comment: I don't see anything special in your case. Describe your model and task in more detail.

Comment: `System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult<Product>` doesn't have any `.Include()`

Comment: @Owl First, according to tags this is EF6, not EF Core you are linking to. Second, this *is* a specific case, and the specific case is *calling a stored procedure* rather than letting EF create a query for you.

Comment: @Dr.Snail Shortly, what are you asking is not possible. If you need EF out-of-the box entity services like `Include`,  don't use SPs. Or let the SP return just ids, and then use regular LINQ query with `Include`s and `Contains` based predicate.

Comment: Even at the SQL level, stored procedures aren't *composable*, meaning, you can't do `exec Sproc AS sp JOIN Table1 AS t1 ON ...`. So, even if EF would be willing to support this scenario it wouldn't have the means.

Answer (score 0):

While using entity framework people tend to use **Include** instead of **Select**. The result seems to be the same, however there is a slight difference.

The difference between `Include` and `Select` is that `Include` fetches the complete object, while `Select` fetches only the selected data. Another difference is that your `DbContext` object remembers the `Included` data.

Databases are extremely optimized in fetching data. One of the slower parts of the query is the transfer of the selected data from the database management system to your process. Hence it is wise to limit the amount of fetched data.

Suppose you have database with `Schools` and their `Students`: a straightforward one-to-many relations: Every `School` has zero or more `Students`, every `Student` studies at exactly one `School`, using a foreign key to the `School` he attends.

Let's query `School` [10] with its thousand `Students`:

```
var result = dbContext.Schools
                      .Include(school => school.Students)
                      .Where(school => school.Id == 10)
                      .FirstOrDefault();
```

The Complete Student is transferred. Every Student will have the same foreign key `SchoolId` value 10. So this same number is transferred a thousand times (1001 if you also count School.Id), while you already know the value. what a waste of processing power!

> When querying data, always use **Select** to fetch the data. Only use **Include** if you plan to update the fetched data

```
var result = dbContext.Schools
    .Where(school => school.Id == 10)
    .Select(school => new
    {
        // Select only the School properties you plan to use
        Id = school.Id,
        Name = school.Name,
        Address = school.Address,

        Students = school.Students
            .Where(student => ...) // only if you don't want all Students
            .Select(student => new
            {
                 // again: select only the properties you plan to use
                 Id = student.Id,
                 Name = student.Name,
                 ...

                 // not needed, you already know the value!
                 // SchoolId = student.SchoolId,
            })
            .ToList(),                     
    })
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

I've use new to create an anonymous type. This is the most efficient. If you really need to create Schools and Students, use `new School` and `new Student`

```
.Select(school => new School
{
     ...
     Students = schoolStudents.Select(student => new Student
     {
         ...
     })
     .ToList(),
})
```

A last remark. `include(school.Students)` can be found in `using System.Data.Entity`

Comment: As usual, abstract lecture w/o respecting the concrete question. I don't see anything in this "answer" that addresses the title of the post and the statement at the very beginning **"I want to call a procedure and access the navigation properties afterwards"**.

Comment: Often it is better to learn someone how to fish, instead of giving him a fish. Besides, OP asked: "Is there a kind of Include() function or something else to speed up my code?" My answer tried to explain: yes there is: use Select